# How can I get CPU usage per task on Symbian^3?

Tags: symbian, symbian3

Is there a tool to see CPU usage of a task/thread on a Symbian^3 phone?

Using PerfMon I only see the global CPU usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I didn't put the CPU count per process there, since you can not really get it. Also the global CPU measurement is a bit fake to be fully honest. its simple having a idle-priority timer going off, and if it goes off everytime then there is no CPU load, and if it never gets off, then the CPU load is 100 %. In efect its a bit relative, but have to say it has worked on the tasks I have needed it for..

BTW, re-did the site, and now all Symbian apps are at: http://www.drjukka.com/YBrowser.html, lets see how long it takes me to push all codes into the Github, anyway, they'll end up there hopefully before 7th birthday of the Y-Tasks app.

Comment: thx for the answer however we dropped symbian platform eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

May be Dr. Yukka's Y-Task application will be useful: http://www.drjukka.com/YTasks.html

Comment: I tried that, doesn't show this. Maybe symbian doesnt have this info.

Comment: If you'll take a look at the RThread class - http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Kernel_Architecture_2/RThreadClass.html - you'll find the GetCpuTime(...) method, which can help you. But I guess you'll have to write such thread explorer by yourself.

Comment: cool, this looks like a good lead. I can take it from here. Thank you. Put it as separate answer so i can vote this one